# How to update data used by kendo.observable object using ajax? Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

Is it possible to affect data asynchronicaly (ajax) that is used by kendo.observable object in Kendo UI?

With below code `cart.add()` function is triggered and `cart.contents` variable is updated, but this not affect the template and not refreshing data used by template. I'm expecting that changing cart.contents changes data used by template, like `text: quantity` and `text: itemPrice`

template script 1:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="cart-preview-template">
  <div id="shop-info" data-bind="attr: { class: cartContentsClass }">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="source: cart.contents" data-template="cart-item" id="shop-list"></ul>
        <div id="shopping-cart">
            <p class="total-price" data-bind="html: totalPrice"></p>
            <a id="empty-cart" href="#" data-bind="click: emptyCart">empty cart</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

template script 2:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="cart-item">
    <li class="selected-products-list">
        <a data-bind="click: removeFromCart" class="view-selected-items">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: imageSource, alt: imageAlt }"
            />
        </a>
            <span data-bind="text: quantity"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: itemPrice"></span>
        </span>
    </li>
</script>
```

model:

```
var cartPreviewModel = kendo.observable({
                cart: cart,

                cartContentsClass: function () {
                    return this.cart.contentsCount() > 0 ? "active" : "empty";
                },

                removeFromCart: function (e) {
                    this.get("cart").remove(e.data);
                },

                emptyCart: function () {
                    cart.empty();
                },

                itemPrice: function (cartItem) {
                    return kendo.format("{0:c}", cartItem.item.unitPrice);
                },

                imageSource: function (cartItem) {
                    var baseUrl = "{{ absolute_url(asset('images/products/')) }}";
                    return baseUrl + cartItem.item.image;
                },

                imageAlt: function () {
                    return "Product image";
                },

                totalPrice: function () {
                    return this.get("cart").total();
                },

                proceed: function (e) {
                    this.get("cart").clear();
                    sushi.navigate("/");
                }
            });
```

object observable cart used by:

```
        var cart = kendo.observable({
            //for testing purpose, just to show cart panel bar at start with some items. 
            //originally it should be: contents: []
            contents: [{"item":"productID":1,"unitPrice":"111.00","image":"5.jpg"},"quantity":1}],
            add: function (item) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{{ path('add_product') }}',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {'item': JSON.stringify(item)},
                    success: function (sessionCart) {
                        // original code: 
                        // this.contents = sessionCart;

                        // code for testing, just to be sure new data is set:
                        this.contents = [{"item":{"productID":1,"unitPrice":"111.00","image":"5.jpg"},"quantity":1},{"item":{"productID":2,"unitPrice":"999.00","image":"8.jpg"},"quantity":1}];
                    },
                });

            },
```

binding model and template:

```
kendo.bind($("#shop-info"), cartPreviewModel);
```

Once again, With above code `cart.add()` function is triggered and `cart.contents` variable is updated (while debbuging) but this not affect the template and not refreshing data used by template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `set()` function to change property values on an observable in order to trigger any bindings to update.

***So change this:***

```
this.contents = [
  {"item":{"productID":1,"unitPrice":"111.00","image":"5.jpg"},"quantity":1},
  {"item":{"productID":2,"unitPrice":"999.00","image":"8.jpg"},"quantity":1}
];
```

***to this:***

```
this.set("contents", [
   {"item":{"productID":1,"unitPrice":"111.00","image":"5.jpg"},"quantity":1},
   {"item":{"productID":2,"unitPrice":"999.00","image":"8.jpg"},"quantity":1}
]);
```